# Ajax form send error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm have a `form` that sends data to a server. When the form is usual HTML it works fine. All data is sent to the server without error. However when I change the form to use AJAX I get an error.

```
<form id="form" action="handler.php" method="POST"> <!-- it's work -->
    <input id="contact_name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="NAME">
    <input id="contact_phone" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="PHONE">
    <button type="submit">Get call</button>
</form>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    /*this does not work*/
    $('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
        var dataf = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'handler.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: dataf,
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
            },
            error: function(response) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
            }
        });
    });
});
```

In console I get this:

```
{"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}
```

Comment: what error you got ? could you please post that error ?

Comment: use `contentType: "application/json; charset = utf-8",
            dataType: "json",` in ajax

Comment: @AtalKishore why? He's sending serialized form data

Comment: The [`error` handler](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) receives three parameters. You've posted the least informative one

Comment: go to in your console just right to the source there is network tab click on that you will see handler.php file click on that and see what error it showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `e.preventDefault();`

```
$(document).ready(function(){/*this does not work*/
  $('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var dataf = $(this).serialize();
      $.ajax({
        url: 'handler.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: dataf,
        success: function(response) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        },
        error: function(response) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        }
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: How will this change the result of the `$.ajax()` call?

Comment: It is just wrong. Arsalan metioned the same issue. Clicking the button the form is submit by button and forwarded to handler.php. If then is still an error we should know the code from handler.php.

Comment: it's true! and it's work.. but i'm dont understand why? is 'preventDefault' important part of ajax query ?

Comment: @KonstantinMokhov: I have edited my latest comment. Other Option is to use just a button and not a submit button. `preventDefault` stops sending you forward to handler.php by form. So you remain on current page and receive AJAX result.

Answer (score 0):

`<button type="submit">Get call</button>`

should be

`<button type="button">Get call</button>`

Since you are submitting it manually via jQuery.

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` is needed if the buttin type is submit, change the button type to simple button and you wont need  `e.preventDefault();`